# onLongPress click show Text Widget show same page right 0 side bottom -10

Tags: flutter, widget

**What Type Of widget use**

1 . Show New Widget in Same Page in
2 . expame css use position absolute ,any Widget in flutter
3 . i want blow the image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mM1bS.jpg)

**My Current Code**

```
class MyItemsItem extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  MyItemsItem({
    super.key,
    required this.item,
  });

  final ItemBucket item;
  late SupportAction supportAction;
  @override
  ConsumerState<MyItemsItem> createState() => _MyItemsItemState();
}

class _MyItemsItemState extends ConsumerState<MyItemsItem> {
  List<String> visibleDeleteButtonIds = [];

  String deleteBtnShow = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            InkWell(
              splashColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 196, 196, 196),
              onTap: () {
                MyItemUtils.goToMyItemChildren(
                  context: context,
                  pathName: PathName.myAddItem,
                  itemId: widget.item.id,
                  callback: (res) {
                    ref
                        .read(addItemListControllerProvider.notifier)
                        .refreshState();
                  },
                );
              },
              onLongPress: () {
                setState(() {
                  deleteBtnShow = widget.item.id;
                  // widget.supportAction.persist.deletePayment(widget.item.id);
                  // if (!visibleDeleteButtonIds.contains(widget.item.id)) {
                  //   print('work this line');
                  //   visibleDeleteButtonIds.add(widget.item.id);
                  // }
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    const Expanded(flex: 1, child: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart)),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 8,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                widget.item.description!,
                                style: CustomStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ).textStyle,
                              ),
                              Text(
                                '+3',
                                style: CustomStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ).textStyle,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 4,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '200',
                            style: CustomStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontSize: 16,
                            ).textStyle,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Divider(
              height: 2,
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 126, 126, 126),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        if (widget.item.id == deleteBtnShow)
          Positioned(
            width: 100,
            right: 0,
            bottom: 0,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: const ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  ref
                      .read(addItemListControllerProvider.notifier)
                      .deleteItem(widget.item.id);
                  deleteBtnShow = '';
                });
              },
              child: Text(
                'Delete',
                style: CustomStyle(color: Colors.black).textStyle,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

**My Current Code Preview**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSyVn.png)

**Reslove this Problam**
Which Type of Widget Use and how bottom -10 how provide

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.